# Using a Logitech c310 Camera with Linux Mint

Tags: linux, linux-mint, logitech-webcam

I've never used or installed a webcam before, so bear with me. I plugged the camera into a USB port and nothing happened. What should happen? How do I mount the camera? It didn't come with directions, only a disc for Windows (I'm running Linux, see below).

I would like to use the Gmail video chat.  Again, I have never used a Webcam before so I have no idea of where to start.

I am running:

- Linux Mint 14 Nadia Cinnamon 64 bit
- Logitech HD Webcam c310

Comment: Have you tried [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=linux+mint+logitech+cam)? What are you trying to do? Take pictures? Skype?

Comment: Have a look what dmesg says when you plug it in

Comment: According:
http://www.matthartley.com/logitech-hd-webcam-c310-on-linux-mint/
Webcam in your case has to work.
Run lsusb (as root) and provide output...

Comment: If your camera was recognized properly, you should see a new device: `/dev/video0` or `videoN`. But that still doesn't guarantee it will work with cheese, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is very likely your camera actually works out of the box. Install a program that uses it such as `skype` or `cheese`.

1. See if the camera works

   ```
    sudo apt-get install cheese
    cheese
   ```

If everything is OK, that should show you a live feed from the camera.

2. Install video4linux control panel to be able to tweak the settings

   ```
    sudo apt-get install v4l2ucp 
    v4l2ucp
   ```

Comment: For me installing `v4l2ucp` helped.